# HtmlAgilityPack - Unable to get nested element innerText from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to get data from a table with this structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="border_tbody">
        <tr style="height:55px;">
            <th class="heading_one" colspan="2">Heading 1</th>
            <th class="heading_two">Heading 2</th>
            <th class="heading_three">heading 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ro">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/vendors_images/vendors_ficon/a.png" height="17px" width="17px" alt="a" title="a">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td td="" class="l no_border">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    Vendor name
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="l lo" style="text-align: center;"><a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">15%</a></td>
            <td class="l bonus_amount">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" class="apply_text" target="_blank">
                    <div class="coupon_div">
                        <span class="coupon_span">
                            <span class="card_secondary_text">$10</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="ro">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/vendors_images/vendors_ficon/a.png" height="17px" width="17px" alt="a" title="a">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td td="" class="l no_border">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    Vender name
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="l lo" style="text-align: center;"><a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">6%</a></td>
            <td class="l" style="text-align: center;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="ro">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/vendors_images/vendors_ficon/a.png" height="17px" width="17px" alt="a a" title="a a">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td td="" class="l no_border">
                <a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">
                    Vendor name
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="l lo" style="text-align: center;"><a href="go/a/a.com" target="_blank">5%</a></td>
            <td class="l bonus_amount">
                <a href="apply/a" class="apply_text" target="_blank">
                    <div class="coupon_div">
                        <span class="coupon_span">
                            <span class="card_secondary_text">$50</span> - Apply
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am able to get the inner text from the second td[2] (vendor name) and third td[3] (percentage). Where I'm having trouble is getting the inner text of the fourth td[4] since the nested elements vary if they contain text or not.

The table above shows the three variations and here is the code I have so far.

```
foreach (var table in webDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody"))
{
    // skip the first tr since they are headings.
    foreach (var tr in table.SelectNodes("tr[position() > 1]"))
    {
        if (tr != null)
        {
            var vendorName = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[2]/a").InnerText.Trim();
            var rateOne = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[3]/a").InnerText.Trim();

            // Unable to get the inner text at this point
            // var rateTwo = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[4]/a/div/span/span").InnerText.Trim();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get text from cell, because there is no text... OK, so what is the problem? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example HTML given in the question, it looks like the class name is always the same for the fourth cell. If not, you can iterate over all the descendant nodes looking for text that starts with the dollar sign:

```
HtmlDocument webDoc = new HtmlDocument();
webDoc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (var table in webDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody"))
{
    foreach (var tr in table.SelectNodes("tr[position() > 1]"))
    {
        if (tr != null)
        {
            // [1] class name in HTML sample always the same
            var rateTwo = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[4]//span[@class='card_secondary_text']");
            Console.WriteLine("Method 1 Coupon: {0}",
                rateTwo != null ? rateTwo.InnerText : "none"
            );

            // [2] brute force - all descendants
            var rateTwo2 = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[4]").Descendants();
            if (rateTwo2.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in rateTwo2)
                {
                    if (child.InnerText.StartsWith("$") && child.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element) 
                        Console.WriteLine("Method 2 Coupon: {0}", child.InnerText);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method 2: No coupon");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Method 1 Coupon: $10
Method 2 Coupon: $10
Method 1 Coupon: none
Method 2: No coupon
Method 1 Coupon: $50
Method 2 Coupon: $50
```